# Can't flash Samsung Tab A6 2016 (SM-T585)

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, device-firmware, odin

My Samsung Tab A6 2016 (SM-T585) doesn't boot when I press the power button and volume down. I did nothing, I was using it last night like every day, but today that happened. It says

> An error has occurred while updating the device software.
> Use the Emergency recovery function in the Smart Switch PC software.

I tried to enter download mode and flash it with Odin. I downloaded the corresponding Samsung firmware (maybe) but it fails in Odin. Sometimes Odin says the repartition operation failed, sometimes there is no PIT partition. I don't know if there's any Odin alternative or something I can do.

Comment: How did the device got into that non-booting state? Have you tried to root it or install a custom ROM? Or did this happen all of a sudden?

Comment: Non i did nothing, i was using it last night like everyday, but today that happened.

Comment: If you did nothing and considering the age of your tablet and the error messages you describe it could be a defect flash memory.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Based on screenshots with a similar error, I think there should be another error message showing on the top-left of that screen. Could you mention it?